# Compare two arrays, if values are in array, add to list, if not add values to another list. No duplicates

Tags: arrays, algorithm, powershell, multidimensional-array, data-structures

please look at the comments in code and see if you can help me with this
I am checking to see if a value from $arr1 is in $arr2. If it is, add it to a list,
if it is not, add it to another list. Make sure both list/arrays do not have
duplicates.

```
$arr1 = @(1,2,3,4,4,2,5,7,9,9,1) 
$arr2= @(5,1,2,3,6,8,1) 
$NotinList = @()
$inList = @()
$counter = 0

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $arr1.length; $i++){
    for( $j = 0; $j -lt $arr2.length; $j++ ){  
        if($arr1[$i] -ne $arr2[$j]){ #check to see if value from $arr1 is in $arr2
            for($k = 0; $k -lt $NotinList.length; $k++){ #Traverse through empty array
                write-host $arr1[$i]  
                if($NotinList[$k] -ne $arr1[$i]){                                        # *^ if empty array does not alreadycontain item from big $arr1, add it.
                    $NotinList +=  $arr1[$i]
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            $inList += $arr1[$i]

            #how would I remove duplicates from number in list since there are repeating numbers in $arr1 that are not in $arr2.

        }
}
$counter++ #keep track may use for something else??
}
```

Comment: You already got two answers to an almost exact same question as your [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69638688/compare-duplicates-in-an-array-list-values-that-are-contained-and-not-contained) and both answers cover your need.

Comment: Not even close. I do not want to perform those operations ".Add" operations I need everything to be within a certain space time complexity. I want to remove the duplicates in the most efficient way.

Comment: I already have the solution that got the job done, but I want to do it the way up above.

Comment: What do you mean you don’t want to do those “add” operations? What you’re doing here with += is one of the worst things one can do in regards to performance.. let alone “space time complexity”

Comment: Is there another way that is more efficient? I guess using the '+'  instead of '+='

Comment: I don't see how adding to a system.array which is actually recreating the array on each iteration (your code snipet) can be more efficient to adding values to a generic list.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with powershell but if you have a solution please share or any links to similar problems and I will take a look.

Answer (score 2):

I would eliminate the duplicates first and then use the `Where()` array operator to split the array into the variables.

```
$arr1 = 'a','b','b','c','d','e','e','f','g'
$arr2 = 'a','b','c','g'

# not in list = d, e, f
# in list = a, b, c, g

$inlist,$notinlist = ($arr1 | Get-Unique).Where({$_ -in $arr2},'split')
```

Now here is what each contains

```
$notinlist
d
e
f

$inlist
a
b
c
g
```

Comment: Nice, thats a good solution

Comment: Very clever with the split call.

Comment: Nice, but note that since `$arr1` in the question isn't _sorted_, you cannot use `Get-Unique` (try `1, 2, 1 | Get-Unique` to see the problem) - either use sorted input or use `Select-Object -Unique` (which, unfortunately, is implemented quite inefficiently as of PowerShell 7.2 - see [GitHub issue #11221](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11221)). Depending on the size of the arrays, performing a linear lookup in the other array (`-in $arr2`) in each `.Where()` iteration could become problematic - but is definitely not a problem with the arrays as small as the sample array.

Comment: Or `([System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]$arr1).where({....})` can work too

Comment: I see, sort-object -Unique works but is it better than select?

Comment: My question was never answered. This is not about using any .sort or get-unique pre defined methods. I want to do this at a "low level". my program up above may not be efficient but I want to do it only using like a c++ or java way of doing it if that makes sense.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, go use Java or C++

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on doing it manually, I recommend using hashtables. They are extremely fast and the keys have to be unique.

If you care about the order you can use `[ordered]` hashtables

```
$arr1 = 1,2,3,4,4,2,5,7,9,9,1
$arr2= 5,1,2,3,6,8,1

$inlist = [ordered]@{}
$notinlist = [ordered]@{}

foreach($entry in $arr1){
    if($entry -in $arr2){
        if($entry -notin $inlist.keys){
            $inlist.$entry = $entry
        }
    }
    else{
        if($entry -notin $notinlist.keys){
            $notinlist.$entry = $entry
        }
    }
}
```

Now your unique lists are in either/both they keys or the values

```
$inlist.Keys

1
2
3
5

$notinlist.Values

4
7
9
```